# how to quote/use variables in curl

Tags: shell, curl, zsh

This works correctly

```
curl --header 'Accept: application/json' www.example.com
```

However, how to achieve this (I want header information in a variable):

```
h="--header 'Accept: application/json'"                                                                                    
curl $h www.example.com                                                                                                         
curl: option --header 'Accept: application/json': is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: Use an array. It's not just the right answer in zsh, but in bash too (though the syntax is a bit different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, unquoted parameter expansions do not undergo word-splitting by default.

```
h="--header 'Accept: application/json'"
curl $h www.example.com  # equiv to curl "--header 'Accept: application/json'"
```

You could enable word-splitting, but then the single quotes remain *part* of the header.

```
curl ${(z)h} www.example.com  # equiv. to curl "--header" "'Accept: application/json'" www.example.com
```

What you want is an array, where the single quotes only serve to escape the space.

The solution is to use an array.

```
h=(--header 'Accept: application/json')
curl $h www.example.com  # equiv. to curl "--header" "Accept: application/json" www.example.com
```

The *array* parameter expands to a sequence of separate words, one per element.